# Trying to create a mySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Here is my table information:

table HOTEL, with attributes hotelid, address, manager name, number rooms, amenities has
primary key hotelid, which is an AUTOINCREMENT type.

table ROOM with attributes number, type, occupancy, number beds, type beds, price, hotel id
has primary key (hotel id, number), and hotel id is a foreign key to HOTEL.

table RESERVATION with attributes hotelid, cust id, room number, begin date, end date, credit card number,
exp date has primary key (hotelid, cust id, room number, begin date), and (hotelid, room number)
is a foreign key to HOTEL.

Updated

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER GoodRoom
BEFORE INSERT ON room
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.type NOT IN ('regular','extra', 'suite', 'business','luxury','family') THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE TEXT 
END IF;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` in phpMyAdmin or similiar or the mysql command line and copy/paste the output to your question for each table you want to tell us about! Then format it so we can read it

Comment: I notice you have some non standard single quotes `‘` and `’` use a text editor to code and not a word processor. They will normally cause compile issues

Comment: @sinisterme I see you have edited the question replacing quotes and != is this question resolved ? If not what's the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

WRONG:

```
IF NEW.type != ('regular','extra', 'suite', 'business','luxury','family') THEN ...
```

RIGHT:

```
IF NEW.type NOT IN ('regular','extra', 'suite', 'business','luxury','family') THEN ...
```

It looks like your conditions are pretty simple. You should consider using [CHECK constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) instead of a trigger, assuming you are using MySQL 8.0.16 or later.

Also if you use SIGNAL to throw user-defined errors, the SQLSTATE should be `'45000'`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html says:

> To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means “unhandled user-defined exception.”

Comment: Bill thank for the help. I will make those changes and repost. I have to use a trigger.

Comment: It's a homework question, and the instructor is requiring a trigger. You can tell that it's homework by some of the phrasing in the post, especially the use of "we" as the pronoun and  the second NOTE. I think the entire Problem: paragraph is a direct quote from the assignment.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't mind helping folks with homework, if they have shown some effort and just need a tip. I think this is pretty much the official stance I've seen discussed on the meta site.

Comment: @BillKarwin: I didn't mean to imply that you'd done something wrong. I was simply pointing out that the OP had an assignment that required a trigger. I have no issue with homework questions that show a sincere effort.